# Inheritance of multiline helm chart template

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I want to set resources to pods with helm chart with template of resource section from subchart. Because it should be several different reource templates in subchart.
I have **values.yaml** , **main-values.yaml** and **templates/deployment.yaml**
The command to update helm chart is

```
helm upgrade -i mynamespace ./kubernetes/mynamespace --namespace mynamespace --create-namespace -f kubernetes/mynamespace/main-values.yaml --reset-values
```

Files are cuted to show just an example:
main-values.yaml :

```
namespace: mynamespace
baseUrl: myurl.com
customBranch: dev

components:

  postgresql:
    nodeport: 5432

  elasticsearch:
    nodeport: 9200

resources_minimum:
  requests:
    memory: "100M"
    cpu: "100m"
  limits:
     memory: "300M"
     cpu: "200m"
```

values.yaml

```
namespace: 
baseUrl: 
customBranch: 

components:
  service:
    name: service
    image: docker-registry.service.{{ .Values.customBranch }}
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    resources: "{{ .Values.resources_minimum }}"
    tag: latest
    port: 8080
    accessType: ClusterIP
cut
```

And deployment.yaml is

```
cut
      containers:
        - name: {{ $val.name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml $.Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ tpl $val.image $ }}:{{ $val.tag | default "latest" }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ $val.imagePullPolicy }}
          resources: "{{ tpl $val.resources $ }}"
cut
```

And the deployment section of resources does not work at all. However image section with intermediate template **{{ .Values.customBranch }}** works and nodeport template works fine in **services.yaml**

```
spec:
  type: {{ $val.accessType }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ $val.port }}
      name: mainport
      targetPort: {{ $val.port }}
      protocol: TCP
      {{ if and $val.nodeport  }}
      nodePort:  {{ $val.nodeport }}
```

I've tried **$val**, **toYaml**, **tpl** , and plain **$.Values** options in resources section of deployment.yaml and got several errors like:

> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.resources_minimum":interface {}(nil)}

or

> error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 29: could not find expected ':'

and other error like so.

Is it impossible to push yaml values of multiline **resources_minimum** through **values.yaml** to deployment.yaml?
Which syntax should I use?
What documentation can you advice me to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Fellows helped me with elegant solution.
values.yaml :

```
resource_pool:
  minimum:
    limits:
      memory: "200M"
      cpu: "200m"
    requests:
      memory: "100M"
      cpu: "100m"
...
components:
  service:
    name: service
    image: docker.image
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    tag: latest
    resources_local: minimum
```

And deployment.yaml :

```
          {{- range $keyResources, $valResources := $.Values.resource_pool }}
            {{- if eq $val.resources_local $keyResources }}
              {{ $valResources | toYaml | nindent 12}}
            {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
```

Any sugestion what to read to get familiar with all Helm trics?

Comment: why `nindent 12`? how you now what number to use to use `12`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use template code in values.yaml files.
But you can `merge` several values.yaml files to reuse configuration values.

main-values.yaml

```
components:
  service:
    image: docker-registry.service.dev
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "100M"
        cpu: "100m"
        limits:
          memory: "300M"
          cpu: "200m"
```

values.yaml

```
components:
  service:
    name: service
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    tag: latest
    port: 8080
    accessType: ClusterIP
```

If you add this to your template, it will contain values from both value files:

```
components: {{ deepCopy .Values.components | merge | toYaml | nindent 6 }}
```

- `merge` + `deepCopy` will [merge the values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#merge-mustmerge) of all your values files.
- `toYaml` will output the result in yaml syntax.
- You also have to check the correct indentation. 6 is just a guess.

Call `helm template --debug ...`
This generates even invalid yaml output where you can easily check the correct indentation and see other errors.

Comment: Thank you for your guess! But if I put `resources: {{- toYaml .Values.resources_minimum | nindent 6 }}` in values.yaml I'm getting error such as: **converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.resources_minimum | nindent 6":interface {}(nil)}** . If I put that statement in double quotes then I'm getting **at <$val.resources>: wrong type for value; expected string; got interface {}**

Comment: My idea is to have one deployment.yaml file with sting like **resources: _put here the resources value of multistring yaml template from values.yaml where it has been substituted from my-values.yaml file_**

Comment: I misunderstood your question first. So I changed my complete answer. I hope this is what you need, though I did not fully understand what you want to do with the `component:` part in your values file and what values you really want to include in the final chart.

Comment: Hi @Climber123, please tell if the updated answer solves your question.

Comment: @MatthiasM I've stopped on this solution: in deployment.yaml `{{ if $val.resources_minimum_selector }}
          resources: {{ deepCopy $.Values.resources_minimum | merge | toYaml | nindent 12 }}
          {{ else if $val.resources_average_selector }}
          resources: {{ deepCopy $.Values.resources_average | merge | toYaml | nindent 12 }}
          {{ else if $val.resources_maximum_selector }}
          resources: {{ deepCopy $.Values.resources_maximum | merge | toYaml | nindent 12 }}
          {{ end }}
          env:`

Comment: in values.yaml `resources_minimum:
  limits:
    memory: "200M"
    cpu: "200m"
  requests:
    memory: "100M"
    cpu: "100m"

resources_average:
  limits:
    memory: "500M"
    cpu: "500m"
  requests:
    memory: "200M"
    cpu: "200m" `
And describing of containers is such: `components:
  service:
    name: service
    image: image
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    tag: latest
    port: 8080
    accessType: ClusterIP
    resources_average_selector: true`

Comment: and Nothing of resources in main-values.yaml BTW there is an idea how to put valid json into text multiline template. But it not tested yet. I'will leave a comment after I test this trick.